# Programmatically repeat "Detail" section in Active Reports

Tags: activereports

I need to repeat a "detail" section, simply repeating the data found in XML, based on the value of one of the XML elements.

Example:

I have a shipped quantity on a line item of 18. There is only one set of data for this in the XML, it is not repeated 18 times. I would like it to display this data 18 times.

Is there a way to programmatically repeat a section? I'm a total novice and i figured for once I'd ask here instead of going to the software vendor, in which case i learn nothing! I tried pouring over the 800+ page manual and couldn't find an answer.

Any solution where I'm not just repeating the detail section is of course welcome!

The report is coded in VB.net, my dataset is XML.

Thanks in advance!

Shawn

Answer (score 0):

I understand your requirement and as per my understanding you wish to repeat the data in the detail section depending on the value of the 'Shipped Quanity'.

If the value is 18, the details section should be repeated 18 times and if ofr the next record the value if 5, the entry for this record should be dispalyed in the report for 5 times.

A cleaner to implement this without repeating the Details Section of the report would be to make use of a subreport.

The flow of the implementation would like the following :

1. Add a subreport in the Detail section of Report1 (Main Report)
2. Set it's datasource and add the fields you wish to display
3. You may remove the ReportHeader/ReportFooter of the subreport and set the height of the PageHeader/Footer to zero
4. In the Format event of the Detail section fetch and save the value of the 'Shipped Quanity' in some variable (say count).
5. On the basis of this value, 
   a. either repeat the Detail Section (number of times=value of count) of the Subreport 
   b. or render the Subreport multiple times (number equivalent to the value of count)

Regards,
Mohita

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a counter system and LayoutAction (which i didn't know existed before making this question)

The code ends up looking like this:

```
int counter = 1; 
int skip = 1; 
public void Detail_Format() { 

if (skip == 1) 
{ 
string convert =((TextBox)rpt.Sections["Detail"].Controls["txtShipQuantity"]).Text.ToString(); 
counter = int.Parse(convert); 
} 
if (counter > 1) 
{ 
rpt.LayoutAction = LayoutAction.PrintSection|LayoutAction.MoveLayout; 
counter--; 
skip = 0; 
}   
else 
{ 
rpt.LayoutAction = LayoutAction.PrintSection|LayoutAction.MoveLayout|LayoutAction.NextRecord; 
skip = 1; 
} 
}
```

Thanks!

Shawn